# LWIP library files not building on Atmel 7.0 when setting NO_SYS=1

Tags: build-error, atmelstudio, lwip

I've got a strange question that I can't seem to find any answers for. I'm building a quite simple application for sending/receving data from/to a PCB, and the application itself builds, but when I exited Atmel Studio (Version 7.0) and reopened the project, the library files no longer built. At least that's what I think happened. I didn't change any code between building the project before and after restart of the program. It has happened before, and that time I solved it by creating the project from scratch, but I'd really like that not to be the only solution. I've also tried restarting the program again, as well as the computer. I also removed and re-added the library.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? If so, any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Information on my system and error messages below:

I'm building for the ATSAMV71N21B board, with Atmel Studio 7.0. I've imported the lwip library trough the ASF wizard, and these files built before the program restart.

These are the files that won't build:
 [image: Unbuildable files]

The 122 build errors mainly consists of "expected expression before 'struct'" and undeclared functions and variables, even though these clearly are defined in the various files in the library.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being because of my NO_SYS setting being 1. When I switched it to 0, everything built, (except for sys_check_timeouts(), but I think I'll find another answer for this). Keeping this here for reference if anyone needs it one day.